# Can you somehow combine the probabilities of two events?

Tags: probability, statistics

I know P(A|X) and P(A|Y), and I'm interested to compute/estimate P(A|X,Y). I suspect it cannot be done directly: if I know that 30% of women have blue eyes and 20% of english people have blue eyes, I can't directly estimate how many english women have blue eyes because I'd find out the percentage of women in England; OTOH, if I know the percentage of women in England then I don't care how many english people have blue eyes.

I guess my question is - can I combine these two informations somehow? What is the minimum (additional) information that I need to find out (or estimate) in order to compute P(A|X,Y) ?

Comment: You are right, of course. If $50\%$ of the women in the general populace have blue eyes, and $50\%$ of all englishmen have blue eyes, then it could be that the blue-eyed Englishmen are all male, or all female, or anywhere between (assuming equal gender distribution), meaning you don't know jack squat about $P(\text{Blue eyes} \mid \text{Woman}\cap \text{English})$. With your numbers, you can say that it's not above $40\%$, but that's as far as it goes.

Comment: But what I can't tell is if I can add some information, say P(foo), such that using P(foo) and P(A|X) and P(A|Y) I can compute P(A|X,Y); but just using P(foo) and either one of P(A|X) or P(A|Y) (not both of them) would be insufficient to compute P(A|X,Y)